# Javascript - Text field is not supposed to auto fill with the saved username

Tags: javascript, html

A html input field is auto filled with a username saved in the browser sign in form. Two months ago, this resolved the issue with this code.

```
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered">
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered">
```

But I believe this week, chrome had an update and it broke the fix. This fix works with firefox, but it looks like chrome has gotten smarter and has turn my fix into a problem-unresolved. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You can use the `autocomplete` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: I get users who report this autocomplete as a bug all the time (and they don't want to be bothered with learning how to disable it in their own browsers). There are plenty of common scenarios in which a webpage needs to prevent that autocomplete; for security reasons, or for a "create / edit user profile" page, for example. Users don't just like it, they demand that we web developers keep coming up w/ workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I tried them all. I got it working. I ended up using this:

```
$('#selectedID').append('<input style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">');
$('#txtselectedID').append('<input type="UserName" style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">');
```

But for another page, I used this: and it worked when this one didn't.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //======fix for autocomplete
    $('input, :input').attr('readonly', true);//readonly all inputs on page load, prevent autofilling on pageload

    $('input, :input').on('click focus', function () { //on input click
        $('input, :input').attr('readonly', true);//make other fields readonly
        $(this).attr('readonly', false);//but make this field Not readonly
    });
    //======./fix for autocomplete
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`style="display: none;"` will 'hide' the element from the DOM.

You should use the `autocomplete` HTML attribute instead.

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered">
<input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered">
```

More about autocomplete attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about autocompletion?

If yes, use the 'autocomplete' attribute and set it to 'off'.

More info here
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Later edit:
This won't work on all the browsers for all the types of inputs.
Apparently using autocomplete on the form element is widely supported.
https://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete

```
<form autocomplete="off">
 <input autocomplete style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered" autocomplete="off">
 <input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: Most browsers ignore this, that's why tricks like this are necessary.

Comment: Just checked and you're right :). autocomplete off on the form element seems pretty well supported? Haven't tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the method you used for fake inputs so that autocompletes won't fill is right. Use `autocomplete="nope"` for the input fields of username and password. That might solve the issue sometimes.

Comment: `nope`? That's pretty informal.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know why but it worked for me when I used that for my website.

Comment: It actually works because its an invalid value so it 'breaks' the autocomplete functionality. That said, apparently 'nope' no longer works in the newest versions of Chrome. Its almost like they dont want us to turn it off ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('focus,click', '#input_pass', function(e) {
    $("#input_pass").attr("type", "text");
    $("#input_pass").attr("type", "password");
});
```

this how 'play it'